# Calling a custom function in drools lhs

Tags: java, drools

I need to write a custom function that does some checks on the facts in drools working memory and returns a number.

As far as I've figured out - I need to import the helper class which has the custom function.

Now how to access the working memory from the function? And how would I call that function in the LHS?

Comment: If I remember correctly, you simply import the static function, then you can use it. You can then pass parameters to it for your processing

Comment: so I whould have to make a separate list of facts and pass that? Or is there any way to access all the facts directly?

Comment: Don't access data in working memory unless it is via facts matched by patterns and bound to variables which you pass as parameters to your static method. That said, you could rig up a class with a static member that is set to the working memory object references, you can call any suitable method to retrieve facts wholesale and do what you please. But be aware that you are bypassing the reevaluation effect due to changes in working memory for this LHS evaluation.

Comment: @laune I did not understand what you meant by "rig up a class with a static member that is set to the working memory object references" then "call any suitable method to retrieve facts wholesale". Can you elaborate or provide an example please?

Comment: I'm not going to provide an example unless I have a good idea what sort of checks need to be done on which selections of facts.

Comment: The problem for which I am working on a solution is described in the other drools question [Drools rules implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31279457/drools-rule-implementation). If it is possible to do with drools, then the JAVA part would not be necessary. I am no expert in drools, but I would be capable to do the algorithm in JAVA. I just don't understand your method of getting the necessary facts to the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functions can't actually access the working memory. You could bind the required facts in your rule and then send them as parameters to your function.

A better approach would be to use a Query instead of a function. 
You can read more about queries in Drools' documentation: http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.3.0.Beta1/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#QuerySection

Comment: The function would be used to do some calculations based on the facts. I assume the calculations can not be expressed in drools DSL, so an external function needs to be used. Is the Query necessary, wouldn't accumulating all the facts and then passing to the function/method suffice?

Comment: I think is a design question. Functions are not optimized by Drools, they are re-evaluated every time that is required. If you want to reuse a function in more than one rule, then each of the rules have to collect all the necessary facts that have to be passed to the function.

In the other hand, a Query could bring some improvements in execution time because of the way Drools optimizes some of the patterns in a rule/query. A Query is also more encapsulated: it can retrieve from the session any fact that is required for the calculation.

Comment: But I think that all boils down to what you want to do inside the function/query.