# Drools rule implementation

Tags: java, drools

I have a rule that I do not know if it is possible to implement in drools.

The description: `A`, `L`, `P` are all facts/POJOs which are connected. I need to find out if each `A` can be assigned to a free `P` through `L`. And if not, how many `A` elements are left unassigned.

[image: Fact model diagram]

In the case above one `A` will be left unassigned.

I thought up an algorithm that is simple to describe:

1. Find `A` with least edges

   - If `A` has no edges, increase result counter by 1, remove `A`
2. Choose random `L`->`P` from that `A` and remove the `A`, `L`, `P` elements
3. Repeat until there are no `A` left

I'm having a hard time describing that in drools. I'm no expert in drools rules. In JAVA, you'd have to do a lot of manipulations with collections, including sorting, which drools does not seem to support. Is it possible to do this somehow in drools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a set of rules that implements the algorithm. It will not be very efficient on large numbers of As and Ps. A pure Java solution shouldn't be all that difficult either. Note that a complete sort isn't necessary after removing one A from the set and clearing away all dangling L and P objects.

```
rule findMin
when
    $mina: A( $edges: edges )
    not A( edges.size() < $edges.size() )
then
    System.out.println( "retract " + $mina );
    retract( $mina );
end

rule countFail extends findMin
when
    eval( $edges.size() == 0 )
then
    Main.counter++;
    System.out.println( "fail to match " + $mina );
end

rule matchLP extends findMin
when
    $l: L( this memberOf $edges, $p: p )
then
    retract( $p );
    retract( $l );
    System.out.println( "retract " + $p + " and " + $l );
end

rule cleanup
salience 10
when
    $l: L( $p: p )
    not P( this == $p )
    $a: A( edges contains $l )
then
    retract( $l );
    modify( $a ){
        remove( $l );
    }
    System.out.println( "cleanup " + $l + ", " + $a );
end
```

Comment: That's awesome. I did not know about the extend stuff. About the retractions: since there are more rules to be processed, is it possible to store the retracted facts to reinsert them back after the "countFail" rule no longer matches? Or copy the facts to work on separately from the working memory? I'm using drools to count a score, so retracting those facts would change it.

Comment: I think I can make it work with agenda groups. First process all the other rules, then process these algo rules.  Listen for any retractions from the java side and reinsert all retracted objects when done with all the rules with KieSession. Something like this might work.

Comment: Retract and insert are second-best if you need to do more with these facts because all rules will be reevaluated even if you use agenda groups. - A flag in A and P objects is preferable.